# Opencart 1.5.4 Search by Description

Tags: search, opencart

I have read various entries about searching by description and subcategories in opencart by default but I have a unique problem. **I have two header files because my site has 2 headers**... one for the home page and one for every other page.

Home Page:
https://garrysun.com/

Other Page:
https://garrysun.com/ayurveda-products/categories

When I search on the **home page** I get the **correct results** (search the word "heart") but when I search any **other page** it **doesn't return the search for descriptions or subcategories**.

Home Page Search Results:https://garrysun.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_description=true&filter_sub_category=true&filter_name=heart

Other Page Search Results:https://garrysun.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_name=heart

As you can see, when I search the other page the extra code is not being added to search in descriptions and subcategories.

**So why is this new code that I added working for the home page an not any other page?**

To make this search function work I have changed the common.js file to look like this (adding the two lines below each "url= $(base..." section:

```
/* Search */
    $('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';
        url += '&filter_description=true'; // ADDED this to search descriptions
        url += '&filter_sub_category=true'; // ADDED this to search sub-categories

        var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name) ;
        }

        location = url;
    });

    $('#header input[name=\'filter_name\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';
            url += '&filter_description=true'; // ADDED this to search descriptions
            url += '&filter_sub_category=true'; // ADDED this to search sub-categories


            var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

            if (filter_name) {
                url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name) ;
            }

            location = url;
        }
    });
```

Both header files use the same code to call the search function:

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="button-search"></div>
    <?php if ($filter_name) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $filter_name; ?>" />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" name="filter_name" value="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" onclick="this.value = '';" onkeydown="this.style.color = '#000000';" />
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to figure out what's wrong in your code for few minutes (unsuccessfully), I ran a network debugging and found out that nothing is wrong with your code, you are just calling 2 different Javascript files(!):

On your home page, you are using common.js that is located at `https://garrysun.com/catalog/view/javascript/common.js`.

On your category pages, you are using common.js that is located at `https://garrysun.com/catalog/view/javascript/add2cart-go2cart/common.js`.

The 2nd one does not include your modifications, and looks like this:

```
$('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

        if (filter_name) {
            url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
        }

        location = url;
    });

    $('#header input[name=\'filter_name\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

            var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').attr('value');

            if (filter_name) {
                url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
            }

            location = url;
        }
    });
```

Vuala.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you! I was beating myself over the head trying to figure that out. Works great!